# Сумма цифр натурального числа из массива

Tags: java, массивы, циклы, while, for

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int amountOfNumbers = in.nextInt();

    int[] a = new int[amountOfNumbers];
    int[] b = new int[amountOfNumbers];
    int[] c = new int[amountOfNumbers];

    int[] numbers = new int[amountOfNumbers];
    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < amountOfNumbers; i++){
        a[i] = in.nextInt();
        b[i] = in.nextInt();
        c[i] = in.nextInt();
    numbers[i] = (a[i]*b[i])+c[i];
    }

    int x = 0;
    int s = 0;

    for(int j = 0; j < amountOfNumbers; j++){
        x = numbers[j];
        while ( x!= 0){
            s +=x%10;
            x/=10;
        }
        System.out.print(s+" ");
    }

}
```

}

Возникла такая проблема: Я хочу, чтобы пользователь вводил сначала число(amountOfNumbers), которое будет количеством тестов для моей программы.
Далее вводится (amountOfNumbers) чисел и после того как наполнится 3 массива должно произойти вот что:
Первое число A из массива a множится на число B из массива b, после к чего к ним добавляется число из массива C. После таких операций, из чисел, например, 11 9 1, получается 100 (11*9+1). После этого, цифры из этого числа я хочу сложить, и в итоге выводится число 1(1+0+0). Тоесть, если в ввод будет таков: 
3
11 9 1
14 90 232
111 15 111
 то вывод будет таков: 
1 16 21.
Но у меня при таком вводе выводится:
1 17 18. Подскажите пожалуйста, мне, неопытному, в чём же заключается проблема? :)

Comment: Проблемa заключается в [не]умении делить большую и сложную задачу на маленькие и простые.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(int j = 0; j < amountOfNumbers; j++){
    s = 0; // !!! обнуляем сумму для каждого числа в массиве
    x = numbers[j];
    while ( x != 0){
        s += x % 10;
        x /= 10;
    }
    System.out.print(s + " ");
}
```

Замените, пожалуйста, название переменной `amountOfNumbers` на `count`.

Comment: Как же это банально просто. Спасибо большое, я только начинаю изучать язык :)

Comment: @NazariiKlymok На здоровье. Успехов!